# Issue with resolving browserify dependencies

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, browserify

I build a javascript module with a Main class, and a Tools class in a separate file:

### A javascript library `somefancylibrary`

Main:

```
import Tools from './Tools';
class Main {
    constructor() {
        console.log(new Tools());
    }
}
export default Main;
```

Tools:

```
class Tools {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Tools yay");
    }
}
export default Tools
```

I build a module using browserify like this:

```
browserify --debug -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ] src/Main.js  -o dist/Main.js
```

### Using `somefancylibrary` in another project

When I, in a separate project include this library using `npm link` and load:

```
fancylibrary = require('fancylibrary')
```

(I also use browserify in this project, so everything is wrapped up in a bundle.)

I get the following error in the console:

```
    bundle.js:1 Error: Cannot find module './Tools' from '/Users/andreas/wc/mainproject/dist'
```

Apparently the reference to `./Tools` inside the library is attempted to be resolved relative to the main project.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What do you have as `main` in your `package.json`? Source code or browserified version?

Comment: main points to the browserified bundle.